# Put the created sticker into inventory CS GO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I just created a sticker in cs go, uploaded the sticker into the workshop. Then filled in all my payment, and tax information. How to add the sticker into my inventory ?

Answer (score 7):

In CS:GO, your sticker needs to be voted positively (by a fairly big number of people) and it'll get reviewed by Valve after that. If they feel like the sticker fits the game, it'll be accepted and will be considered for distribution through a sticker capsule.

You can see more info on [the CS:GO workshop FAQ](http://blog.counter-strike.net/workshop/faq.php):

> [image]

So, no, you can't simply get the sticker to your inventory.